# How to match single image taken from camera with list of images saved in hive locally in flutter

Tags: flutter, image

I am trying to compare the one photo from camera with 100+ images saved in hive locally, and find out the most matched one in flutter.
For example I want to find out the the information of one book in front of me by taking photo of the book cover and see if any book cover saved in hive is showing in the photo.

Maybe I used it wrongly, I tried image_compare package while it took time to give me the  because it compared the pixel one by one even for 2 image comparison.

Want to know if there is any more efficient way or package to use in this case?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the following use case altered to your case. Hope this will answer your query.

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
void main() {
  ImageLocalModel saveImageInHive = ImageLocalModel(base64Image: '',imageName: 'image1',pickedAt: DateTime.now().toString());
  ImageLocalModel pickedImage = ImageLocalModel(base64Image: '',imageName: 'image1',pickedAt: DateTime.now().toString());
  //Check directly with equal operator
  print(saveImageInHive == pickedImage);
}

class ImageLocalModel extends Equatable {
  final String base64Image;
  final String imageName;
  final DateTime pickedAt;

  const ImageLocalModel({
    required this.base64Image,
    required this.imageName,
    required this.pickedAt,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [base64Image, imageName, pickedAt];

  factory ImageLocalModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ImageLocalModel(
      base64Image: json['base64Image'],
      imageName: json['imageName'],
      pickedAt: DateTime.parse(json['pickedAt']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'base64Image': base64Image,
      'imageName': imageName,
      'pickedAt': pickedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
  }
}
```